# How can i find a phrase duplicates in list?

Tags: python, list

there is a list like that:

`my_list = ['beautiful moments','moments beautiful']`

don`t look at grammar, the main idea is that those two strings are about same thing.

The question is how to detect that those phrases are duplicate WITHOUT splitting and sorting each phrase?

Comment: Why *WITHOUT*? what's wrong with splitting?

Comment: Without splitting, how do you delimit words? At some point you will have to split

Comment: i need to return to user his list in original condition, but without duplicates

Comment: @МаксимМісіченко In you example, which one do you want to keep? first one?

Comment: @S.B no, its unique.

actually i can create a dictionary, that will contain counter as a key and a list with 2 copies of my phrase as a value. Then i can make any operations with one copie of my phrase and decide is it a copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of `frozenset`s here because they are *hashable*(They can be added to the set - Time complexity of membership testing for sets is O(1)) and have equality comparison of `set`s(Two sets are equal if they have the same items in **any order**).

Basically we iterate through the items of the list, split them and make frozenset out of them. There is a `unique` set that we check to see if our item is present there or not.

```py
my_list = ["beautiful moments", "moments beautiful", "hi bye", "hi hi", "bye hi"]

unique = set()
result = []

for i in my_list:
    f = frozenset(i.split())
    if f not in unique:
        unique.add(f)
        result.append(i)

print(result)
```

ourput:

```
['beautiful moments', 'hi bye', 'hi hi']
```

Comment: Note that, since set-like things dedupe, `"hi"` and `"hi hi hi hi hi hi"` would be considered equivalent. If you need the counts of each word to matter, you'd probably need to make your own `collections.Counter` subclass (adding hashing) and/or store `frozenset`s created from a `collections.Counter`'s `.items()` (so they include values and counts). More complicated, but there's no easier option when the counts matter.